# Find the furthest node in a network using R igraph

Tags: r, igraph

How can I find the node that is furthest to another node in a directional network?

For example in the following code:

```
g <- graph( c('A',1,'A',2,'2','B','B',4,'B',5,5,'C','C',7,'C',8,'D',7,8,'D'))
```

How can I get the furthest node from B, being "7" (B>5>8>D>7) or C, being also "7" (C>8>D>7)

Thanks

Comment: `igraph` has a function for determining distances: e.g. `distances(g, 7)`.

Comment: Is it the case to get the max value I guess. Sounds good. Thanks

Comment: Yes, for example `plot(g);V(g)[4];d <- distances(g, 4, mode = "out");d <- d[1, !is.infinite(d)];d[d==max(d)]` gives you the node(s) with the maximum distance from the 4th node in your graph.

Comment: Yes!!! This is awesome!! Thank you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple matrix multiplication. For example, the following code shows the paths from C (the 7th node) of length 1,2,3,4. By length 4 there are none.

```
ga <- get.adjacency(g, sparse = F)
for (i in 1:4) {
print(i)
print(matrix.power(ga,i)[7,])
}
```

Though it may not be practical if your graph is very large.

Comment: Thanks jac. What library are you using for matrix.power?

Comment: It's from the package `matrixcalc`. But you can also use something like `Reduce("%*%", rep(list(ga), i))`

Comment: Thanks lukeA. Very helpfull.